# The meaning of item in the function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, json, jquery

I borrowed a piece of code from somewhere, but I don't understand it. It is kind of ajax call webservice.

```
function SearchMyStuff() {
$("#tblHouse").hide();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageName + "SearchMyStuff",
    data: "{'oParams':" + JSON.stringify(BuildMyStuffSearch()) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d.length > 0) {
            while ($('#MyStuffBody tr').length > 1) {
                $('#MyStuffBody tr:last').remove();
            }

            $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
                var templateRow = $('#templateMyStuff');
```

What I want to know is

```
function (index, item)
```

What is **index** and **item** here.

Thanks for explain it.

Comment: index is loop variable index  and item is the current traversed element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words:

```
$.each(array, function (index, item) { 
    //body
});
```

is shorthand equivalent of:

```
for(var index = 0; index !== array.length; index++){
    var item = array[index];
    //body
}
```

<sub>Of course,it's far more simplyfied equivalent of real `$.each` implementation</sub>

Comment: @Love Yes, [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) belongs to `jQuery` lib.

Answer (score 3):

The `index` value represents the `index` from within the element array, and the `item` value represents the `element` itself.

Answer (score 1):

$.each loops over each element in an array calling a callback with these parameters

`index` the current index, `item` the value at the current index